# Cannot load markdown.md inside index.js

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am building markdown previewer and I want to add a placeholder for my <textarea> element.

Placeholder is written in markdown and I am trying to import it to my index.js file

```js
import placeholder from './sample.md'; // Importing from the local folder


const $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

marked.setOptions({
    breaks: true
});

let renderer = new marked.Renderer();
renderer.link = function(href, title, text) {
    return `<a target="_blank" href="${href}">${text}` + `</a>`
}

let txtArea = $('textarea')[0];
txtArea.addEventListener('input', event => {
    $('.prev-text')[0].innerHTML = marked(event.target.value, {renderer: renderer})
});
```

I want to use the content of the "sample.md" and save it to a variable "placeholder" so that I can set it
as a default text inside my <textarea>.

Right now I cannot load the "sample.md", browser is throwing this error:"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/markdown". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Markdown Previewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="editor">
            <div id="ed-navbar" class="navbar">
                EDITOR
            </div>
            <textarea name="markdown"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="preview">
            <div id="pr-navbar" class="navbar">
                PREVIEW
            </div>
            <div class="prev-text">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, the clue is in the error message. `import` is looking for a module script, but you're trying to load markdown. You should look at the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) instead.

Comment: I solved my issue using the `fetch` and then using `text` method on the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, thanks for help everyone, wouldn't have done it without You!

```js
const mrk = new Request('sample.md');

fetch(mrk)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(text => {
        $('textarea')[0].innerHTML = text;
        $('.prev-text')[0].innerHTML = marked(text, {renderer: renderer})
    });
```